# Minimize json for better readability

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, json, web

I have json which contains more than 6000 lines. I want to make it more readable. As you can see the json structure below there are some commn stuff present in all the enviroments ('commonA', 'commonB') , is there any way to manage common stuff in another file and variable stuff in separate files (so that readability improves) and finally we can link those files here in the main file to complete this structure.

Json Structure

```
{
    "feature": {
        "dev":{
            "commonA": {},
            "commonB": {},
            "variableDev": {}
        },
        "stage":{
            "commonA": {},
            "commonB": {},
            "variableStage": {}
        },
        "local":{
            "commonA": {},
            "commonB": {},
            "variablelocal": {}
        },
        "prod":{
            "commonA": {},
            "commonB": {},
            "variableProd": {}
        }
    }
}
```

common json present in single file and variable json present in different files and somehow we can link those files to main file to complete the original sturcture.

Comment: json can't do that. YAML can.

Comment: Is there any way to use Java Script for this @gog

Comment: Rather than re-asking your question, it is better to [edit] this one with updates.  Since your new question has an answer, I'm voting to make this one a duplicate of that one.