# Minimize Object for better readability

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, json, web

I have js object which contains more than 6000 lines. I want to make it more readable. As you can see the object structure below there are some commn stuff present in all the enviroments ('commonA', 'commonB') , is there any way to manage common stuff in another file and variable stuff in separate files (so that readability improves) and finally we can link those files here in the main file to complete this structure.

Object Structure

```
let obj = {
    "feature": {
        "dev":{
            "commonA": {},
            "commonB": {},
            "variableDev": {}
        },
        "stage":{
            "commonA": {},
            "commonB": {},
            "variableStage": {}
        },
        "local":{
            "commonA": {},
            "commonB": {},
            "variablelocal": {}
        },
        "prod":{
            "commonA": {},
            "commonB": {},
            "variableProd": {}
        }
    }
}
```

Common part present in single file and variable part present in different files and somehow we can link those files to main file to complete the original sturcture.

Comment: What is the question? Have you read how to use [CommonJS modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) or [JavaScript modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules)?

Comment: If it's always the same no matter the environment why not create one called shared or constant (or something similar) and move them in there

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Minimize json for better readability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74846964/minimize-json-for-better-readability)

Answer (score 1):

Try Javascript `proxy` as mentioned in [mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)

```
const target = {
  message1: "hello",
  message2: "everyone",
};

const handler3 = {
  get(target, prop, receiver) {
    if (prop === "message2") {
      return "world";
    }
    return Reflect.get(...arguments);
  },
};

const proxy3 = new Proxy(target, handler3);

console.log(proxy3.message1); // hello
console.log(proxy3.message2); // world
```

In your case we can do it like

```
const commanKeys = {
    commonA: "hello",
    commonB: "everyone",
    commonC: "ok",
    commonD: "fromCommanKeys"
};

const proxyHelper = {
    get(target, prop, receiver) {
        console.log(`%cparentKey: ${target.parentKey}`, "color: green");
        if (prop === "commonA") {
            // custom logic for A
            return "A";
        }
        else if (prop === "commonB") {
            // custom logic for B
            return "B";
        }
        else if (prop === "commonC") {
            // custom logic for C
            return "C";
        }
        else{
            return Reflect.get(...arguments)
        }
    }
};

let obj = {
    "feature": {
        "dev": {
            "utils": new Proxy({...commanKeys, parentKey: "dev"}, proxyHelper),
            "variableDev": {}
        },
        "stage": {
            "utils": new Proxy({...commanKeys, parentKey: "stage"}, proxyHelper),
            "variableStage": {}
        },
        "local": {
            "utils": new Proxy({...commanKeys, parentKey: "local"}, proxyHelper),
            "variablelocal": {}
        },
        "prod": {
            "utils": new Proxy({...commanKeys, parentKey: "prod"}, proxyHelper),
            "variableProd": {}
        }
    }
}


console.info(obj.feature.dev.utils.commonA);
console.info(obj.feature.dev.utils.commonB);
console.info(obj.feature.dev.utils.commonC);
console.info(obj.feature.dev.utils.commonD);

console.info(obj.feature.prod.utils.commonA);
console.info(obj.feature.prod.utils.commonB);
console.info(obj.feature.prod.utils.commonC);
console.info(obj.feature.prod.utils.commonD);
```

### Output Log

```
parentKey: dev
A
parentKey: dev
B
parentKey: dev
C
parentKey: dev
fromCommanKeys
parentKey: prod
A
parentKey: prod
B
parentKey: prod
C
parentKey: prod
fromCommanKeys
```